# How to execute functions from packages using function reference in perl?

Tags: perl, module, reference, package

I wanted to use function reference for dynamically executing functions from other packages.

I have been trying different solutions for a while for the idea and nothing seemed to work!
So, i thought of asking this question and while attempting to do so, **solution worked!** but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do so: it requires manual work and is a bit "hacky".  Can it be improved?

1. **A package to support required functionality**

   ```
   package Module;

   # $FctHash is intended to  be a Look-up table, on-reception 
   # of command.. execute following functions

   $FctHash ={
       'FctInitEvaluate' => \&FctInitEvaluate,
       'FctInitExecute' => \&FctInitExecute
   };

   sub FctInitEvaluate()
   {
       //some code for the evalute function
   }

   sub FctInitExecute()
   {
       //some code for the execute function
   }
   1;
   ```

**2. Utility Script needs to use the package using function reference**

```
    use strict;
    use warnings 'all';
    no strict 'refs';

    require Module;

    sub ExecuteCommand()
    {
      my ($InputCommand,@Arguments) =@_;
      my $SupportedCommandRefenece = $Module::FctHash;
         #verify if the command is supported before 
         #execution, check if the key is supported
         if(exists($SupportedCommandRefenece->{$InputCommand}) )
         {
           // execute the function with arguments
           $SupportedCommandRefenece->{$InputCommand}(@Arguments);
         }
      }

      # now, evaluate the inputs first and then execute the function
      &ExecuteCommand('FctInitEvaluate', 'Some input');
      &ExecuteCommand('FctInitExecute', 'Some input');
    }
```

But now, this technique seems to work!  Still, is there a way to improve it?

Comment: Perl is not JavaScript. you introduce a comment with "#", not with "//". The parenthesis on the lines with "sub" declarations do not do what you think they do. Eliminate them, eg sub ExecuteCommand {...}

Comment: The ampersand prefixes on your function calls (`&ExecuteCommand(...)`) do not do what you think they do, either.  Eliminate them, too.

Comment: @Dave, actually, I modified his code to make it look (a) readable (b) Perl.  But now I'm in doubt: maybe it was JavaScript...

Comment: @Pavel: I took a look at the original version in the question's revision history and, no, it was Perl-code-trying-to-use-//-comments from the start.  You didn't break it, it was broken to start with.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `can`. Please see [`perldoc UNIVERSAL`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) for details.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
require Module;

sub ExecuteCommand {
    my ($InputCommand, @Arguments) = @_;
    if (my $ref = Module->can($InputCommand)) {
        $ref->(@Arguments);
    }
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've built a fairly standard implementation for using a hash as a dispatch table.  If that's your intention, I don't seen any reason to do more than clean it up a little.  `can` is a good alternative if you're attempting to build something OO-ish, but that's not necessary if all you're after is a command lookup table.

Here's a version that a) is runnable Perl as it stands (your attempt to mark comments with `//` in the question's version is a syntax error; in Perl, `//` is the 5.10-and-higher "defined-or" operator, *not* a comment marker) and b) has more of a perlish accent:

**Module.pm**

```
package Module;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

our $function_lookup = {
    FctInitEvaluate => \&init_evaluate,
    FctInitExecute  => \&init_execute,
};

sub init_evaluate {
    say 'In init_evaluate';
}

sub init_execute {
    say 'In init_execute';
}

1;
```

**script.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

require Module;

execute_command('FctInitEvaluate', 'Some input');
execute_command('FctInitExecute',  'Some input');

sub execute_command {
    my ($input_command, @arguments) = @_;
    $Module::function_lookup->{$input_command}(@arguments)
      if exists($Module::function_lookup->{$input_command});
}
```